# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges not working on certain devices

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

I have an app the uses CLLocationManager's significant location change API while in the foreground. On certain devices I am seeing unexpected behavior where a call to startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges has the following effects:

1. The location services icon turns on in the status bar.

   The location services icon turns off after about 10 seconds.

   The location manager's location property seems to give the location at the time monitoring was started, but it never changes, regardless of whether or not the device location changes.

   The delegate's didUpdateToLocation and didFailWithError methods are never called, regardless of whether or not the device location changes.

One of the devices is a current generation iPod. The other is an iPhone 5S. Both are running 7.1. In both cases [CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable] returns true.

It appears that these devices are in some kind of weird state where access to the GPS is allowed, but significant change monitoring doesn't work, but I can't think why.

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: How far did you move the device? You have to move for a few hundred feet in order to be sure to get an update.

Comment: I moved about 600 feet.